# Why are <beans> attributes required in applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, spring

The attributes of beans tag used in my program are:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
```

Why and what does each of the attributes specify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are namespace declarations. Every element in an xml ideally has to be bound to a particular schema. Those attributes are needed if you want to use multiple Spring features like AOP, transactions, etc.

Please read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) for XML schema and namespaces